# ruby version on macOS Sierra

Tags: macos, ruby

Can someone let me know the version of ruby on macOS sierra? I have a public beta of macOS Sierra (10.12.1 build-16B2327e) and the version is 2.0.0.

I wanted to know if the stable version of macOS has a higher ruby version than 2.0.0.

Answer (score 7):

`ruby --version` says:

> ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16 revision 53162) [universal.x86_64-darwin16]

macOS Sierra 10.12 (16A323) release installed from the App Store with XCode 8 installed

Update: macOS 10.13.3 has

> ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [universal.x86_64-darwin17]

Comment: is the macOS app store version or a beta version?

Comment: Just a normal store download.

Comment: This is also the version that ships with macOS Sierra 10.12, independent of whether you have Xcode installed.

Comment: macOS 10.14 (Mojave) has `ruby 2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [universal.x86_64-darwin18]`.

Answer (score 2):

Using the first version of macOS Sierra 10.12 (Build 16A323), released on September 20, 2016 via the Mac App Store:

```
$ ruby --version
ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16 revision 53162) [universal.x86_64-darwin16]
```

This is on a fresh install *without* Xcode installed. All users on *any* version of Sierra should have *at least* this version of Ruby available.

Also, I’ve verified that this same version is still present after upgrading to macOS Sierra 10.12.1 (Build 16B2555) via the Mac App Store.

Answer (score 1):

I like using

```
$ ruby -v
```

Ruby comes installed on macOS but the version is going to be older.

I had to install the newer version

If you have rvm installed already do rvm install <version you want> 
like this:

```
$ rvm install 2.3.3
```

then make it the default like this:

```
$ rvm --default use 2.3.3
```

Source: [rvm website](https://rvm.io/rubies/upgrading)